# Store an array in an object and use a getter method

Tags: arrays, perl, object

I'm struggling with the difference between arrays and scalars.

I initialize an object from [`Config::IniFiles`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles). One of the object properties is an array. During the init method, I can print the array values and the array size.

#### My ini file

```
[project]
junk = Perl
junk = is
junk = complicated
```

From the init method, called inside constructor

```perl
my $ini = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "config.ini", -default => 'Default' );
my $junk = $ini->val( 'project', 'junk' );
my @junk = split( /\n/, $junk );

say scalar @junk;

foreach ( @junk ) {
    say $_;
}

$self->{_junk} = @junk;
```

#### Output, as expected

```
3
Perl
is
complicated
```

Now, I implemented the getter method:

```perl
sub getJunkPatterns {

    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{_junk};
}
```

And call it like this

```
my @patterns = $self->getJunkPatterns();    
say scalar @patterns;
say @patterns;
```

The result is not what I expected

```
3
3
```

For scalar (not array) properties this works fine. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with arrays? Does anyone know how to properly get arrays from `Config::IniFiles` without the need to split them?

Comment: What is `ImportConfig::get`? That's not part of Config::IniFiles.

Comment: I can't see any "_object properties_" to be an arrayref (cannot actually be "_an array_") ...?  Where is the line with `ImportConfig::get` from?

Comment: Is this code inside of _your class_, where you use `Config::IniFiles`? Is that what "_from init method - called inside constructor_" means?

Comment: No, it's actually outside in another class.

Comment: The code that you show doesn't do what you say it does. `$self->{_junk} = @junk` will set `$self->{_junk}` to 3, the number of elements in `@junk`, so `say @patterns` in your second code block will also print 3

Comment: *"I changed it, see above"* Please don't do that. You have made nonsense out of some people's comments as well as the rest of your own question, because `$self->{_junk} = ['Test1', 'test2']` produces different results from `$self->{_junk} = @junk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up arrays and array references.

Your line `$self->{_junk} = ['Test1', 'test2']` sets the value of the `_junk` key to an *array reference*. You can tell that from the square brackets `[]`.

To get the array out of the reference, you need to *dereference* it. You can either do that in your getter like this:

```
return @{ $self->{_junk} };
```

Or you define your interface as an array reference and let the user deref it.

```
my @patterns = @{ $self->getJunkPatterns() };
```

Of course you need to have an array reference inside of that key in the first place. It's not possible to put an array inside anything. Data structures with more than one level **have to be references** in Perl.

So wherever you set it, it needs to look something like this:

```
sub setJunkPatterns {
    my ($self, @patterns) = @_;
    $self->{_junk} = \@patterns;
}
```

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

---

You are using `$self` throughout the code, but it appears that you are not inside of a class. `$self` in Perl is used similar to `this` in some other languages. It's the reference to the instantiated object of a class that you are working with, *inside* of that class. So when you instantiate an object of a certain class *outside*, you would **never** call that `$self`.

Comment: I removed the line with test data. After replacing the return statement of my getter with your suggestion, I get `Can't use string ("3") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"`

Im inside a package, just dropped the first lines to keep it clear.

Comment: @Corni then please also show how you are setting it. You probably assigend an _array_ to `$self->{_junk}`, but you need to make that a ref too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @simbabque and @zdim!

Answer (score 3):

I take it that the code section with `$ini->val(...)` is *inside of a class* and that `_junk` that the data is written to is intended to be an array reference, the only meaningful option.

**First**, you can have `val` from [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eshlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.94/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm#val_%28$section,_$parameter_%5B,_$default%5D_%29) return data *either* as a list *or* as a string

> If you want a multi-line/value field returned as an array, just specify an array as the receiver:
>
> ```
> @values = $cfg->val('Section', 'Parameter');
> ```

So instead of assigning to a scalar and splitting into lines just assign to an array.

**Next**, the assignment `$self->{_junk} = @junk;` is most likely wrong, as follows.

The array `@junk` is being assigned to a scalar, the only thing a hash value can be. This means that the operation is in the *scalar context*, in which case what gets assigned is the *number of elements of the array*. So after that line `_junk` has a number instead of being an arrayref, as seen in the ouput. See [context in perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context).

So assign an arrayref, `[@junk]` (or more efficiently `\@junk`, if the surrounding code allows it).

**Finally**, in your getter you can simply choose to return those lines either as a list or as a reference to that list, as the [answer by simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802476/4653379) shows.

But you can also consider returning it like `val` does, as either a string or a list, depending on the [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) in which the method is called. To do this check for the context using [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html). If the method is called in the *list context* we return a list, while in the *scalar context* we return a scalar.

```
sub getJunkPatterns {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return (wantarray)
        ? @{$self->{_junk}};
        : join "\n", @{$self->{_junk}};
}
```

The elements are joined by newline for the scalar return, to mimic what `val` does.  If you'd rather return the reference change the scalar return to `: $self->{_junk};`.

Then you can use it either as

```
my @patterns = $object->getJunkPatterns();
```

or

```
my $pattern_string = $object->getJunkPatterns();
```

If you choose to return a reference to that list in the scalar context, instead of the string with lines, change the getter accordingly and then the returned scalar is an arrayref.

Comment: It's clear that it's a scalar. Bt is it possible to get an array directly from `IniFiles`?

Comment: I was going to include `wantarray`, but I decided to not do that because I figured it's too complicated. Also I didn't want to explain that it should be called `wantlist` really. ;)

Comment: @value = ... does not help. Then I still get an array with one entry, not with three entries. So I might use the wrong ini format?

Comment: @Corni  Right, if you simply use `new` and then `my @values = $ini->val(...)` you are directly using the classes methods.  They are correct.  Then it'd be something with data.

Comment: @Corni I think I got it.  That code in the beginning is in the constructor of your own class?  If so, then when you do `$self->{_junk} = @junk;` you are setting your data to the length of the list.  See the last few paragraphs in my answer.  Then, when you later retrieve that ... yep, it's a number.

Comment: No. The `@junk = $ini->val()` call returns an array with one entry instead of an array with three entries. This happens directly after the call, in the next line. It must be something with my ini format. Dont really know how to put array data in here...Maybe there is a special syntax?

Comment: @Corni Oh, already that line ... then it would be something with data.  I can't readily help with .ini format, sorry.  (It should be explained in `Config::IniFiles` docs?)  However, the other thing is wrong, no question. And there is probably more puzzles, since the output you show last can't be. The `_self` would be a _number_, not an arrayref.  I updated my answer, you may want to read it over again.